# Laravel 5.4 not found the requested URL

Tags: laravel-5, http-status-code-404, url-routing, change-password, forgot-password

I have hosted my Laravel 5.4 website and every thing is working fine but when I try to reset a password, I get this error on live server:

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /password/reset/daf4775f9259b5462a0a6d79d6777884b46a90a76f71be5db773a37967f712c2 was not found on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) PHP/7.1.9 Server at localhost Port 80

The URL that is returned does not match my domain name:
`http://localhost/password/reset/daf4775f9259b5462a0a6d79d6777884b46a90a76f71be5db773a37967f712c2`

How may I change the returning URL to match my domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution, this is happening because i didn't change my site url in .env file